# browserify-shim error when node_modules folder is a symlink

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, node-modules, browserify-shim

On the production server node_modules folder is a symbolic link for continuous deployment purposes.
When I run gulp command, I got many errors like this:

`Error: Unable to find a browserify-shim config section in the package.json for /home/web/www/persist/node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js while parsing file: /home/web/www/persist/node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js]
  filename: '/home/web/www/persist/node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'
. . .`

If I move node_modules in project folder, build process is successfull. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer from **thlorenz** (author of browserify-shim)

> Linking breaks browserify and shim since your projects dependencies
>   are outside of your project tree. So when looking upwards these tools
>   can't find the package.json of your package anymore.
>
> So don't link your node_modules folders .. it's a bad idea anyways
>   since you're then linked to a global in your system, i.e. it's better
>   to have all your deps be local to your project. Not sure what your
>   deployment purposes are, but to me it seems like whoever made that
>   decision didn't fully understand how node/npm is supposed to work.

Comment: Unhelpful. There are valid cases for dependencies being symlinks in `node_modules`, such as multi-package repositories (monorepos).